# CWAC-Camera lag

Tags: android, camera, lag, commonsware-cwac

I'm using the cwac-camera and it seems to work fine. The only problem is when I hit the back button. I'm getting some lag when returning to the previous fragment.
I've tried to change the CameraFragment class by putting the code on the onPause method in an Async task, but nothing changed...

I am sure the problem is with the CameraFragment because I tested with a normal fragment (no camera) and the lag disappeared.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use Traceview and determine where your lag is coming from.

Comment: I solved it. It was my problem. Sorry : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CameraFragment was not being paused because I was using a FragmentAdapter without passing the ChildFragmentManager in instantiation. Consequently the fragments instantiated by the adapter where not being destroyed.